# Python How to send individual message for servers

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello i want to send a individual message for servers when command has invoked.

```
List = ['Server 1 ID' : 'Message 1', 'Server 2 ID' : 'Message 2',]

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(("!Ping")):
        if message.server.id in List:
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, "Pong")
```

So if message server id in that list bot should send that particular message to that server.

Comment: Don't forget the comma for the `startswith` argument: `("!Ping", )`.

Comment: @alecxe  Yeah but how to make it send `Message 1`  if ctx message server id is `Server 1 ID` and `Message 2`  if ctx message server id is `Server 2 ID` .  I need to change something in `await bot.send_message`  but getting confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead of a list

```
messages = {'1234': "Hello server 1!", '5678': 'This is the message for server 2.'}

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(("!Ping")):
        if message.server.id in messages:
            await bot.send_message(message.channel, messages[message.server.id])
```

Comment: Yes thank you it worked. just i changed  `if message.server.id in List:` to 
 `if message.server.id in messages:`